# using the Page Visibility API to add and remove a temporary hash while the page is hidden

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, iphone-standalone-web-app, ios-standalone-mode

I found a medium article that described how to persist user state for a standalone web app on ios or just keeps working after a user has gone offline. On iOS devices, tapping an installed app icon will force a reload of the target URL which erases the current state of the app for the user.
The link to the article is https://medium.com/@samthor/add-to-home-screen-apps-and-their-lifecycles-9ccd05f96e71

I included screenshots of the section in the article I am referring to

[Screenshot number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfMOU.png)

[Screenshot number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy5ky.png)

```js
function visibilityHandler() {
  var hash = '#bg';
  if (document.hidden && !window.location.hash) {
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location + hash);
  } else if (!document.hidden && window.location.hash == hash) {
    var l = '' + window.location;
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, l.substr(0, l.length - hash.length));
  }
};
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', visibilityHandler, false);
visibilityHandler();
```

This code is supposed to persist the state of the user for a standalone web app but it's not working. Could someone please help me? Thanks

Comment: Please define "not working"

Comment: I added this snippet of code to my progressive Webb app and tested it and it doesn’t persist the state of the app which is what this code is supposed to do